# Create Clock countdown timer in php without Jquery / Javascript

Tags: php, timer, gif, countdowntimer

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in php, having style of clock, but without use of JQuery.
In fact I want to use this counter as a gif image to send it in email.

In other words, I would like to get a timer count down like this:

[image]

I goggled a lot, unfortunately I don’t find any great solution.

Can anyone here help me !?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First off, if you DON'T want it in jQuery / JS, why tag your question with jQuery / JS then? - Secondly php is executed server side, so i don't think you can get php to act like a clock without any other tools for it. And I don't think a GIF is a viable option either due to the fact that each time the page refreshed, so will the timer.

Comment: I tagged jQuery to keep jQuery developers in touch with my question, may be someone can help me ...

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking but it sounds like what you actually want is to have PHP dynamically create a .gif for you?

Comment: @BinaryMan Why do you want help from jQuery if you dont want jQuery?

Comment: so, are you finding a counter gif image?

Comment: Dear @Moob, Dear Pepo_rasta, in fact my aim is to create my own counter, by changing the image pixels colors or something like this ...